# (0,n.usePreventRemoveContext) is not a function error in Expo Snack

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to add my app to Expo Snack. It works perfectly outside of Expo Snack but when I added it and added the dependencies, it runs well on the web option but I keep getting an error "(0,n.usePreventRemoveContext) is not a function. (In '(0,n.usePreventRemoveContext)()', '(0,n.usePreventRemoveContext)' is undefined)
(Device)" when I try to run it on iOS or Android options.

I can't find any information on the usePreventRemoveContext function

This is my app: https://snack.expo.dev/@emihardej/sudoku?platform=android
I'm rather new to this and I cannot find the issue, any help to get it to run is much appreciated

I have tried adding and removing dependencies, changing the versions but the error remains.